# Error when redefining \bibname (under T2A encoding)

Tags: input-encodings, cyrillic

I'm trying to compile the following document:

```
\UseRawInputEncoding
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}

\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage[paperwidth=70mm,paperheight=110mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*{\bibname}{Список литературы}

\begin{thebibliography}{00}

\bibitem{bib:1} Лаборес модератиус ид хас, виде ностро еа пер
\bibitem{bib:2} Еу хас яуаестио волутпат репудиандае, иус те
\bibitem{bib:3} Бонорум цопиосае принципес ест ин, глориатур еффициенди
\bibitem{bib:4} Мазим аппетере атоморум ан усу, модус елигенди цум ан.
\bibitem{bib:5} Лаборес модератиус ид хас, виде ностро еа пер
\bibitem{bib:6} Еу хас яуаестио волутпат репудиандае, иус те
\bibitem{bib:7} Бонорум цопиосае принципес ест ин, глориатур еффициенди
\bibitem{bib:8} Мазим аппетере атоморум ан усу, модус елигенди цум ан.
\bibitem{bib:9} Лаборес модератиус ид хас, виде ностро еа пер
\bibitem{bib:10} Еу хас яуаестио волутпат репудиандае, иус те

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

(I must apologise for doing the list that lengthy but the issue doesn't occur for lists of less than two pages.) LaTeX stops with the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character Ү (U+04AE) not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

This is weird since character `Ү` is not contained in the document. I am using MiKTeX 23.1 Portable (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.3.4, LaTeX2e <2022-11-01>) with the latest updates, under Windows 7 (64-bit). Obviously, the error is created by the (re)definition of `\bibname` when the list of references extends for more than one page.

If I ignore the error (by pressing `S`), the document compiles but the running title on the second page is missing the first two letters (`Сп`). If I removes these two letters in the definition of `\bibname` (`\renewcommand*{\bibname}{исок литературы}`), then I get no error. If I remove only the first or the second letter (i.e., only `С` or `п`), I get an even more intriguing error:

```
! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again>
\q__text_recursion_tail
l.57 \end{document}
```

It seems that the letters `С` and `п` have been assigned some special meaning in recent versions of LaTeX.

It should be noted that the described issues do not occur when compiling the document with an older version of LaTeX (namely, MiKTeX 20.11 Portable, preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.6.13, LaTeX2e <2020-10-01>), which I was using before updating my TeX system.

I know that the issue can be solved by using `\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}` (which I cannot do for other reasons). Anyway, my question rather is why the error appears with the latest software versions but not with old ones. This is deceiving since one usually hopes that updates solve old problems and not create new ones (alright, I know I'm being excessively optimistic here). Maybe I am doing something wrong or missing some detail? Any relevant explanation will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why `\UseRawInputEncoding`? Save as UTF-8 and forget about encodings.

Comment: `\UseRawInputEncoding` by design breaks latex's enoding support so you could load some legacy packages. Do not use it here

Comment: Thanks, egreg and David Carlisle for your suggestion. Unfortunately, unicode encoding is not an option for me since other people working with me use WinEdt 5.3 or 5.6, heavily customised, and a LaTeX version dated 2016 or 2017, and they cannot migrate to unicode versions. That's why I use ```\UseRawInputEncoding```. In fact, I was thinking that the newest version of LaTeX, which I am using, contains some bug.